# Formatting HTML using PHP Mail()

Tags: php, html

I'm am sending an email via the php code below, which sends an email template to the users emails address. However the email sends with all the HTML tags still visible and not in effect.

```
$fh = fopen('templates/customer.eml','r');

        $emailContents = fread($fh, filesize('templates/customer.eml'));
        $emailContents = str_replace(":name:", $person->first . " " . $person->last, $emailContents);
        $emailContents = str_replace(":meeting_name:", $meeting->name, $emailContents);
        $emailContents = str_replace(":chair:", $chair->first . " " . $chair->last, $emailContents);

        fclose($fh);

        $header = "FROM: vra@vodafone.com\r\n";
        $header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $header.="Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
        mail($person->email , "Meeting Request", $emailContents, "FROM: user@domain.com");
```

And below is the email template file that I am using for the content:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Dear :name:,<br />
            You have been invited to <em>:meeting_name:</em> chaired by :chair:.
        </p>

        <p>
            Main text of the email will go here<sup>*</sup>.
        </p>
        <p>
            Thankfully
        </p>
        <p>
            User
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't read the $header variable. You are only appending to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing the headers into the mail function. Try:

```
$header = "FROM: vra@vodafone.com\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .="Content-type: text/html; charset: utf8\r\n";
mail($person->email , "Meeting Request", $emailContents, $header);
```

---

Try these headers instead

```
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'From: vra@vodafone.com' . "\r\n";
mail($person->email , "Meeting Request", $emailContents, $header);
```

Comment: Sorry about that my mistake. I have updated the $header into the mail function. However I now don't receive and an email?

Comment: Thanks for posting that code, it worked :) Really appreciate your help. Thanks